# python/django - Why do functions in views.py have request, etc in the brackets?

Tags: python, django

```
def detail(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    return render_to_response('polls/detail.html', {'poll': p}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Why do functions in views.py have request, poll_id in the brackets?

I know in classes it means they are the base class and being inherited from. What do these mean in functions?

got my answer here :

> Once one of the regexes matches, Django imports and calls the given
>   view, which is a simple Python function (or a class based view). The
>   view gets passed an HttpRequest as its first argument and any values
>   captured in the regex as remaining arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are the arguments being passed to the function.

This is really really basic programming. Almost all languages work this way. I recommend you do an introductory programming tutorial.

Comment: lol. silly me. I learnt the basic of functions but the "request" in every django view function confused me.

Comment: @masterpiece The *request* will be passed in by Django framework.